# graph api find friends activity in app

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph

How do I find friends activity within app?

I'd like to do something like this:
https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends/news.reads

I can find my friends in the app with this:
me/friends?fields=installed,name?limit=5000
then pull out the friends with the 'installed' field.

Then I can query each friend by id to get their activity:
/news.reads

But is there some way to combine this query?  It seems like I'm jumping through hoops to get the info I want.

Basically what I'm looking to do, is if I have a URL, find my friends who've read it, and display the last friend.

The 'fb-activity' widget does something similar, but I need more granular control, and I want to do it for a list of URLs, not just the current page.

Any suggestions?

Comment: turns out the appropriate way to do this is to make two calls, one to get a list of your friends, then filter down to the ones who have the app installed (the "?fields=installed" part of the query in my question), then make a second batch call of multiple <friends_id>/news.reads calls.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably better off getting the friends list with FQL instead of filtering:

```
SELECT uid FROM user
WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
AND is_app_user = 1
```

See: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/2785093/facebook-friends-getappusers-using-graph-api